# Compact and Minimal Version of Linux

Tags: linux

I am developing my own OS using Linux From Scratch. For this I should have a host Linux OS. But I'm very confused because of a wide range of Linux products. I just want a compact and minimal version of Linux free of pre-installed applications on which I can just install LFS packages and compile my OS.

My system specifications are:

- Storage-4 GB (as I want to install Linux OS on my flash drive)
- Processor-Intel Core 2 Duo E7500 2.93 GHz, RAM 2 GB, Display Max Resolution-1440x900.

Can someone recommend a Linux OS fitting my needs?

I have recently came across lubuntu 18.04 LTS. Would you recommend that?

Comment: Do you want a prebuilt Linux, or a wizard which will let you tailor your own distro?

Comment: I am using the open source Linux Kernel and want to build my own OS by referring Linux from Scratch Documentation

Comment: Do you need a gui or just plain shell?

Comment: No I need a basic Gui to manage my files and my tasks more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the long time of silence from Software Recommendations Exchange Users, I researched thoroughly and found the most appropriate solution to my problem, that is: lubuntu 18.04 LTS. The download size of its iso file is 1.01 GB (for normal Desktop Installer) and 717MB (for alternate installer). It is compact enough to fit on to my flash drive and boots up very fast. To make it even smaller, one can uninstall the packages that one doesn't want. It provides a simple GUI with a good shell. All the development packages can be installed on it easily.

Please refer lubuntu.net for further information.

Comment: Both of those ISO's are compressed. To make this answer more useful for others, do you know about how much space the *installed system* took up?  (Doesn't need to say how much space you saved by removing packages).

Comment: lubuntu 18.04 takes approximately 2.7 GB of disk space after installation.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across [Alpine Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux). 
"Because of its small size, it's heavily used in containers providing quick boot up times." (Quoted from Wikipedia Article 1st paragraph).

[Thousands of images](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=alpine&starCount=0) in the Docker Hub use it already as a "base OS" for the container. Maybe it's not exactly what you need but it's worth knowing about.

Maybe ask in that community?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create Linux from scratch I recommend that you look into this [site](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/) that is explaining how big boys are doing it. But I can assure you that you are going into the world of pain...

Take a look at the [**linux famility tree**](http://futurist.se/gldt/wp-content/uploads/12.10/gldt1210.png) to decide which OS you really want to chose for your host OS... I chose mine to be minimal debian distribution (debian is grand-father of all linux flavors)... Another way would be to look what OS are supercomputer using (since they use striped OS flavors)... CentOS seems quite popular..

[Top 500 supercomputer OS flavors](https://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/7d0l8j/all_500_of_the_worlds_top_500_supercomputers_are/dpum137/)

I started my own Linux from scratch with minimal Debian distribution and after 2 years of constant unsatisfaction with the final product, I switch to normal Ubuntu distribution that I customized to the full!

This is [my deprecated tool](https://github.com/urosjarc/mylinux) with which I created the automated installation (in case I broke the OS I could easily reinstall it)...
This tool has been in constant development for over 4 years and finally, I was able to stabilize it with the latest ubuntu...

Here is [all configuration](https://github.com/urosjarc/mylinux/tree/depricated/config) of the tool in which you can find scripts, apt, dotfiles for my project... Hope it helps you in some way...

Comment: According to the graph you linked to, Debian, Slackware and RedHat are the grand-fathers of three different GNU/Linux family trees.

Comment: Debian is the oldest so it was used to influence other distros... @jrw32982